# swift closure as an argument trouble me

Tags: swift

```
func compare(arr:[Int],value:Int ,cb:(Num:Int , Value:Int)->Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in arr{
        if(cb(item, value)){
            return true
        }

    }
    return false
}
```

and error as below:

> missing argument label 'Num:Value' in call

```
func compare(arr:[Int],value:Int ,cb:(Num:Int , Value:Int)->Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in arr{
        if(cb(Num: item, Value: value)){
            return true
        }

    }
    return false
}

var v1 = compare([40,53,98,1], 1000, { (num:Int, value:Int) -> Bool in
    return num > value
})
```

Why use do I need to use `(Num: item, Value: value)` instead of `(item, value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's why you specified argument labels as Num and Value.

If you don't want use argument labels, you may not specify labels.

```
func
compare( arr: [ Int ], value: Int, cb: ( Int, Int ) -> Bool ) -> Bool {
    for item in arr {
        if( cb( item, value ) ) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Also you can use '_' to hide the 'value' label of compare function.

```
override    func
viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var v1 = compare(
        [ 40, 53, 98, 1 ]
    ,   1000
    ) { ( num, value ) -> Bool in
        return num > value
    }
}

func
compare( arr: [ Int ], _ value: Int, cb: ( Int, Int ) -> Bool ) -> Bool {
    for item in arr {
        if( cb( item, value ) ) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```